# How to insert line break (enter) in Whatsapp message sent via jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css, encoding, whatsapp

This is how I am sending whatsapp message via jQuery

```js
var ques = "I";
            var a = "am";
            var b = "having";
            var c = "a good";
            var d = "time";
    $(document).on("click", '.whatsapp', function() {
                            var whatsappMessage = ques + "\r\n\r\n" + a + "\r\n" + b + "\r\n" + c + "\r\n" + d;
                            
                            var whatsapp_url = "whatsapp://send?text=" + whatsappMessage;
                            window.location.href = whatsapp_url;
                        
                    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <div id="showques" style="margin-left: 10px;font-size: 32px;">
            </div>
            
            <div style="width:300px;padding: 20px;background-color:#5755d9;">
                    <a class="whatsapp" style="font-size: 40px;color:white; text-decoration: none;">Whatsapp</a>
                </div>
```

output = I \r\n\r\n am \r\n\r\n having \r\n\r\n a good \r\n\r\n time

I want an output like this:

I

am

having

a good

time

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line in the code and it will work

> whatsappMessage = window.encodeURIComponent(whatsappMessage);

```
$(document).on("click", '.whatsapp', function() {
                        var whatsappMessage = ques + "\r\n\r\n" + a + "\r\n" + b + "\r\n" + c + "\r\n" + d;
                        if( isMobile.any() ) {
                        whatsappMessage = window.encodeURIComponent(whatsappMessage);
                        var whatsapp_url = "whatsapp://send?text=" + whatsappMessage;
                        window.location.href = whatsapp_url;
                    } else {
                        alert("Please share this in mobile device");
                    }
                });
```